# What does "such as they are" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions

What is the definition of that phrase? Does it refer to the aforementioned words as bad? Or does it refer to the words as what it is.

Example: “Tonight I am to sup with my lords bannermen, such as they are."

Does this mean his bannermen are bad? Or does this mean his bannermen are bannermen?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. [Please provide some context](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)

Comment: Added information.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/such-as-it-is-such-as-they-are)

> You use such as it is or such as they are to suggest that the thing you have just mentioned is not very good, important, or useful.

And in this case, the author actually goes on to explain what the speaker means. [From here](https://archive.org/stream/ASOIF/2.AClashOfKings_djvu.txt)

> Tonight I am to sup with my  lords bannermen, such as they are. Celtigar, Velaryon, Bar Emmon, the whole paltry lot of them. A poor crop, if truth be told, but they are what my brothers have left me.

Answer (score 0):

Such as it is or such as they are is a subtle expression of disapproval. Other expressions similar to it are " for what it's worth" or " improperly so-called "